# If loop without a boolen condition in c

Tags: c, if-statement

what actually happens in if statement here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int x;
    void main()
    {
      if (x)
         printf("hi");
      else
         printf("how are u");
    }
```

Comment: `if ` statement is not a loop, btw.

Comment: You can consider `if (x)` to be identical to `if (x != 0)`

Comment: If ,is conditional statement i guess.

Answer (score 3):

`printf("hi");` is ran if `x` is non-zero, and `printf("how are u");` runs if `x` is zero.

The conditional check formally uses an `int` type in C (with any other type implicitly converted to an `int` prior to the evaluation); not a Boolean type.

Note that `x` is initialised automatically to 0 in your case as it's at *global* scope.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
if (x)
```

takes the first branch if x is not 0, otherwise the second (else) branch.

Comment: now also how are you only gets printed                                                            #include <stdio.h>
    int x=0;
    void main()
    {
      if (x)
         printf("hi");
      else
         printf("how are u");
    }

Comment: @Bathsheba just changed my name

Comment: @rasmi: since x **is** 0 (at global scope, it is initialized to 0), the second branch is taken: `printf("how are u");`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: What if x is -ve integer??

Comment: @rasmi you still did not got.

Comment: @CommonMan: negative or positive doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is zero or non-zero, where zero can mean NULL for pointers, 0.0 for floating point types, 0 for integral types, false for boolean types, etc.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis , that's makes sense now, better to say it as true. +1

Answer (score 1):

In C any non zero value is equivalent to the `truth` and zero to `false`

So any value is considered as valid logical (even pointers).

```
int *p = malloc(40);;
if (p) printf("Good!!");
```

in your example `x` will be equal zero (unitialized global variables are zeroed) and the `else` printf will be executed.

As the any value which can be converted to integer is valid as logical we can write very short functions like this:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *saveddest = dest;
    while(*dest++ = *src++);
    return saveddest;
}
```

Comment: "we can write very short functions like this"  I wouldn't call this a language feature, but rather a language flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Here int x; is a global uninitialized variable. Compiler initialized the global int variable with 0. In C, 0 means false and 1 means true. Thats why it will print the else part because if(0) means false and compiler will execute the else block i.e. how are u.

Please visit the link for better understanding:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-53/

Comment: I am also surprised !!! I don't know like this here peoples are giving vote . According to me I am correct

Comment: I did not downvote, but " _In C, 0 means false and 1 means true_" should be "In C, 0 means false and non-zero values means true"

Comment: @BishalDubey: But above all, don't take voting (either way) personally; voting is a helpful mechanism - it helps you improve the answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba agree on both the takes, but 1) we really do not consider the `static` initialization rule as the programmer initialization, thus (loosely) we call them uninitialized, 2) 1 means true is not wrong, maybe incomplete, but not a false statement (pun intended) :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks